# Stress testing Azure App Service periodically stops processing requests

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database, stress-testing, azure-app-service-plans

I am currently stress testing a .Net Core application, targeting netcoreapp2.2, that is hosted on Azure as a App Service connected to a P1V2 (210 ACU, 3.5GB memory) service plan with 2 instances.

The endpoint that I'm stress testing is very simple, it validates a Oauth2.0 token, gets the user and some info about the user from a P2 (250 DTU) Azure hosted database, total 4 db queries per request, and returns the string "Pong".

When running 15 concurrent users (or more) in 200 loops I see the stop(s) in processing seen in the image (between the high peaks). The service plan never hits more than around 20-35% CPU and the database never uses more than 2% load. Increasing the users decreases the average throughput.

When looking at the slow requests it is like it just randomly stops, never at the same place. When I look at the DB requests I never see a request that takes longer than a couple of 100 milliseconds while some requests can take upwards to 5-6s to process.

It feels like I reach some limit which results in something stopping for a period of time, but I can't figure out where the problem lies.

When running the same stress locally I don't see these stops.

I'm using jmeter cli to run the stress tests against both environments.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: how do you run the test locally?

Comment: Using jmeter CLI, should have clarified that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of Azure DDOS protection behaviour.

> If your application is being attacked by a DDOS attack, Microsoft will
>   stop all connections to your end point and in effect taking down your
>   service.

To avoid this you need to setup Web application firewall (WAF) to exclude healthy requests.